# How to Compile C++ code using C# application

Tags: c#

I need to compile C++ code in my Windows application and append the results (output or execution errors) to a rich text box.  I use CodeDomProvider Class but I'm unable to compile the code using C++ language. How can I do that?

Comment: This may be a stupid question but are you bundling a C++ compiler with your app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just call the command line C++ compiler (cl.exe) file that comes with VS and pipe the output to somewhere suitable.